# How to change listbox item's color individually programmatically in silverlight?

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0, listbox

I have an chat like tcp application.I want to differ the colors of sent and received messages. How can I do that programmatically?
Any help is appreciated

**Edit**
It would be ok if I can change the row color instead.

Comment: How are you adding items in the list box?

Comment: @Haris Hasan listbox.itemssource = list where list is a type of List<string>

Comment: How would you find out which messages are received and which are sent from List<String>? I am assuming List<String> have both sent and received messages right?

Comment: Do you have another option for me to add items to list please?

Comment: @harris hasan although I change the way of adding items, the porblem still remains

Answer (score 1):

You can change the text foreground of the item.

`item.foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);`

Comment: as indicated from question, I am using listbox.

Comment: regardless, you can still use the foreground property - answer updated to reflect this

Answer (score 1):

ok do this..

Create a class

```
 public class MSGS
    {
        public string color {get;set;}
        public string message {get;set;}
    }
```

now instead of adding items in `List<String>` create `List<MSGS>` and set message equal to message and if message is sent then set color to let's say `Blue` or if message is received set color to `Red`.

```
  MSGS one = new MSGS ();
    one.message = "testing";
    one.color = "Red";

    MSGS two = new MSGS();
    two.message = "testing2";
    two.color = "Blue";

    MSGS three = new MSGS();
    three.message = "testing3";
    three.color = "Red";

    List<MSGS> list = new List<MSGS> ();
    list.Add(one);
    list.Add(two);
    list.Add(three);

    myLB.ItemsSource = list;
```

define a style for listboxitem like this in XAML

```
<UserControl.Resources>

    <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Foreground="{Binding Path=color}"  Text="{Binding Path=message}"/>

                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>

    </Style>

</UserControl.Resources>
```

this code will show the received messages and sent messages in different colors

**More Detailed Approach**
try style below instead of of style above

```
  <UserControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate1">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding message}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate2">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding message}" FontWeight="Bold"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>

        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                        <Grid Background="{Binding Path=type}">
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To=".35" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="fillColor"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To=".55" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="contentPresenter1"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Unselected"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To=".75" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="fillColor2"/>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="contentPresenter1">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                        <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
                                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="contentPresenter2">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                        <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualElement">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                        <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused"/>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <Rectangle x:Name="fillColor" Fill="#FFBADDE9" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0" RadiusY="1" RadiusX="1"/>
                            <Rectangle x:Name="fillColor2" Fill="#FFBADDE9" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0" RadiusY="1" RadiusX="1"/>
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter1" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource DataTemplate1}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"/>
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter2" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource DataTemplate2}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="3,3,0,3" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                            <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisualElement" RadiusY="1" RadiusX="1" Stroke="#FF6DBDD1" StrokeThickness="1" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                            <ListBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="4" Margin="-90,0,0,-163" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="31"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>

        </Style>

    </UserControl.Resources>
```

Have taken this from http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/35969/113333.aspx

If you want to know more about styling check these links

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/pages/silverlight-tutorial-part-4-using-style-elements-to-better-encapsulate-look-and-feel.aspx

http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Skinning-and-Styling-Silverlight-Controls.aspx

Comment: Thank you very very much for this. But ı could not clearly understand how styling works here. Can you help me understand this clearly please. Do you know any resource for learning it

Comment: there is a problem. I cannot select items,some of the functionalities are disappeard. Can you help me about it?

Comment: use the updated code. I know its complex but that's the right way to solve this issue. You can go through links I specified to know more about styling also try googling it you will find a lot of useful stuff

Answer (score 1):

I made an example with binding that makes use of a Style Converter.

You can read the whole implementation and sample here: http://vanderbiest.org/blog/2011/07/12/listbox-individual-item-color-in-silverlight/

Listbox Implementation

```
<listbox itemssource="{Binding Messages}" maxwidth="300" borderbrush="Black" borderthickness="2">
    <listbox.itemtemplate>
        <datatemplate>
                <textblock text="{Binding Name}" style="{Binding IsInError, Converter={StaticResource listboxMessageStyleConverter}}">
        </textblock></datatemplate>
    </listbox.itemtemplate>
</listbox>
```

Converter Implementation

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if ((bool)value)
        {
            return Application.Current.Resources["ListBoxTextNormalItem"];
        }

        return Application.Current.Resources["ListBoxTextErrorItem"];
    }
```

Style Implementation

```
<style x:key="ListBoxTextNormalItem" targettype="TextBlock">
    <Setter Property="Foreground">
        <Setter.Value>
            <SolidColorBrush Color='#0A7B27' />
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</style>

<style x:key="ListBoxTextErrorItem" targettype="TextBlock">
    <Setter Property="Foreground">
        <Setter.Value>
            <SolidColorBrush Color='#FF2A1B' />
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the following link;
http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/74900/455850.aspx
It has working solution of changing the foreground color of selected item. So when you get the message, you mark it as selected item with the style, you can change the foreground color of the text.